# Recuperando string mal-formatada quando contém palavras acentuadas

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, .net

Em minha aplicação estou tendo problema ao buscar os dados no banco PostgreSQL, as palavras com acentuações ao ser recuperadas do banco e lidar no `DataReader` estão vindo mal formatadas como na imagem abaixo.

- No banco de dados com formato correto

[image: SS]

- Sendo lida no `DataReader`

[image: SS]

O Encoding do banco esta em UTF8 e a Character type esta Portuguese_Brazil.1252 se caso ajudar.

Estou lendo os dados da seguinte forma:

```
var command = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from Empresa", con);
con.Open();
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
     Empresa e = new Empresa();
     e.IdEmpresa = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_empresa"]);
     e.NomeFantasia = dr["nome_fantasia"].ToString();
}
```

Segue a imagem para demostrar melhor a linguagem que esta meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostre como você está lendo os dados. Não entendi bem se você está usando UTF8 ou CP1252, são coisas diferentes. Talvez o problema esteja aí.

Comment: certo, coloquei + detalhes respondendo minha pergunta para colocar a imagem

Comment: Você deve [edit] a pergunta e não responder ela com um complemento.

Comment: Como está no conexão? Ela configura o *charset*? Já experimentou usar `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` ou algo parecido?

Comment: PÃ£s é claramente UTF-8 sendo exibido em 1252. Ou você converte pra 1252 pra exibir, ou usa uma saída que mostre UTF-8.

Comment: Um outro exemplo: Ação em UTF-8 fica AÃ§Ã£o em win1252 (ou mesmo ISO-8859-1).

Comment: como posso configurar o charset ou converte-la para 1252 para que mostre as acentuações corretas? sou novato em C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido, em minha ConnectionString informei um Encoding diferente da seguinte forma.

- Antes:

  ```
  Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres; Password=123;Database=gemax;
  ```
- Depois:

  ```
  Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=postgres; Password=123;Database=gemax; Encoding=UNICODE;
  ```

Segundo a documentação do Mono-Project, se houver algum problema com acentuações em UTF-8, recomendasse utilizar UNICODE.

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta ali à esquerda embaixo da votação. Veja [tour].